# Include PHP page and replace divs when link clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to replace a div's contents with another PHP page when clicking on a link.

**Link**

```
echo '<a href="?control=1" name="control" id="controlpanellistt">Control Panel</a>';
```

**If statement checking if link clicked**

```
 <?php 
/** Control panel link. */
    if(isset($_GET['control'])){
        $link=$_GET['control']; 
        if ($link == '1'){
           include('controlpanel.php');
        }
    }
```

**Divs**

```
<div id="divContainer">
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
        <div id="div2">
        </div>
            <div id="div3">
            </div>
</div>
```

I am looking for divContainer to hold the controlpanel.php contents when the control link is clicked and div1 div2 and div3 to be 'removed/hidden'.

I can get both functionalities to work individually but not simultaneously.

The code currently displays the content within the page but not within a div/hiding contents of said div.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of linking in an href, you want to use AJAX/jquery to retrieve controlpanel.php and populate `divContainer`.

Comment: You don't need to echo raw HTML (the link) if you are mixing HTML and PHP, you can simply close the PHP tag, write your link as normal, and then re-open the PHP tag.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with your current style, you could simply amend your conditional to the following:

```
<?php
if ($link == '1') { 
  include('controlpanel.php'); 
} else { ?>
  <div id="divContainer">...</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Alternatively, as suggested, you could use some JavaScript to hotload in the control panel, and in the same breath, hide the divs you need hidden. Something like this (jQuery):

```
function loadPanel() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'controlpanel.php',
    method: GET,
    success: function(res) {
      $('#divContainer').html(res);
    }
  });
}
```

And then bind this to your link.

Comment: This works, however if I have multiple if statements for different pages - they start to become nested which may cause an issue. Sorry - should have been more clear in regards to that.

Comment: Perhaps the JavaScript solution will be preferred in that case? Maybe I'm still not fully clear on the issue. Let me know if that's the case.